# How do I create a category by clicking on an image on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, categories

I want to create search by clicking on a category. I have this code which works

```
<%= search_form_for @q , id: 'myform' , :html => {:class => "form-inline"} do |f| %>

   <%= f.text_field :category_id_eq, value: 1, type: 'hidden' %>
    <%= content_tag(:button, "Foo", :type=>:submit) do %>
    <div class="col-sm-3  ">
      Image goes here
      </div>
<% end %> <% end %>
```

but the button is not the image I want. It is just a big ugly button. Therefore I want to do something like this. Bt it does not work.

```
    <%= search_form_for @q , id: 'myform' , :html => {:class => "form-inline"} do |f| %>

       <%= f.text_field :category_id_eq, value: 1, type: 'hidden' %>
       <div class="col-sm-3  " onclick="document.myform.submit()">
       Image goes here
      </div>
    <% end %><% end %>
```

My question exactly is, how do I turn a div into a submit button? or how can I search by clicking on an image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I solved the problem. The Use the first example which was correct and I simply style it with css.

```
<%= search_form_for @q , id: 'myform' , :html => {:class => "form-inline"} do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :category_id_eq, value: 1, type: 'hidden' %>
  <%= content_tag(:button, "Foo", :type=>:submit, class: 'category_button' ) do %>
    <div class="col-sm-3  ">
       Image goes here
    </div>
   <% end %> 
 <% end %>
```

CSS I reset Code:

```
 .category_button{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;


   }
```